# .NET app service not working with automatic restart

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, web-services, service

We have developed a windows service using C#. The service is deployed on a production windows 2016 server to run 24/7. The functionality of the service is to monitor for a SQL Server 2016 table. Once records are inserted into the SQL Server table, the service reads the records from the table and using the information, makes a web service callout to a third party CRM system with the details.

Most of the time, the service works fine. However, at some times, the service appears to be stuck and not pulling the records from the SQL server table. I had to manually restart the windows service from the production control panel (services.msc) and then it starts working again. This issue is happening at least once in two months or some times more.

I worked with the windows server team and did setup a task scheduler on the production server to restart the windows service on a daily basis thinking that the restart of the service will address the "stuck" issue. However, it doesn't seem to help. The service is getting restarted every day (I can see that from the task scheduler logs), but once the service is stuck, the automatic restart doesn't seem to "free" the service. Even after the automatic restart, the service is in "stuck" mode only. Once I login into production server and restart the service manually, the service immediately starts working and pulls all the records from the SQL server and passes the information to the third party CRM system.

Has anyone experienced similar issues with C# windows service? Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it's leaking something, connections or resultsets? Make sure you're using "using" statements around your db calls. You know that you can also create a memory dump of the service state and then open it in Visual Studio to see where it's stuck at. IF you build a debug mode, you can pretty much step right into C# code

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone experienced similar issues with C# windows service? Any thoughts or suggestions?

If you're restarting the service daily and still experiencing issues, it's vanishingly unlikely that the problem is anything other than a bug in your code.  If you don't know *why* it's failing, then you have two bugs.  One is a serious lack of logging and telemetry to make your program manageable, and the other is whatever is causing your program to fail.